# how to use an angular expression working inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

How do I get an angular expression working inside a script tag... I am pretty new to this and need help? 
Here is an example of my java script code:

```
<script id="modal-2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="modal transparent">
        <div class="card">
            <i class="icon ion-ios7-close close-modal" ng-click="closeModal(2)"></i>
            <div class="item item-divider">
                {{card.title}}
            </div> 
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                {{card.details}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is an example of my array:

```
.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicModal, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $scope.cardss = 
    {id:1, title:'Frank', src:'img/Frank.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
    {id:2, title:'Generali', src:'img/Generali.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
    {id:3, title:'John Lewis', src:'img/JohnLewis.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
    ];
```

Comment: not sure what exactly you're trying to do... why put the html in a script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of cards in the controller so you need to iterate them through using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

```
<script id="modal-2.html" type="text/ng-template">
<div class="modal transparent">
<div class="card" ng-repeat="card in cardss">
<i class="icon ion-ios7-close close-modal" ng-click="closeModal(2)"></i>
<div class="item item-divider">
{{card.title}}
</div> 
<div class="item item-text-wrap">
{{card.details}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

The array in your example was missing the opening square bracket so the array will look like this:

```
$scope.cardss = [
  {id:1, title:'Frank', src:'img/Frank.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
  {id:2, title:'Generali', src:'img/Generali.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
  {id:3, title:'John Lewis', src:'img/JohnLewis.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
  ];
```

Comment: What if I dont't want to repeat the content.. I just want 1 title and 1 details from the array inside the card?

Comment: then you need to access it like this cardss[0].title where 0 is the index of the element in that array you want to access

Comment: Thanks... Can you provide an example?

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/rfft81cL/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special wrt use of AngularJS expressions inside partial templates.

As already said your model is actually array - so you'll have to iterate through the items using [ng-repeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="card in cards">
        Card id: {{card.id}}
        Card title: {{card.title}}
        Card details: {{card.details}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please see working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw2e06h9/) example.